# Django - JAZZMIN

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, backend

I am facing this issue the content field is not showing properly in Page View how can I habdle it.
Check SS given below:
[Django Jazzmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmq7b.png)

```
class Page(TimeStampModel):
    type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(db_index=True, unique=True, choices=TYPE_CHOICES.choices)
    content = RichTextField()

    @property
    def title(self):
        return self.get_type_display()
```

Thanks in advance!

I am implementing DJANGO JAZZMIN in my Project.